# Discount Price by Gaming - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, extensions

Is there any interactive gaming (extensions) which will discount the price as per the points taken by the customer?

Ex. A spinning wheel with values.

Comment: i heard about reward point extension but its new concept great..if you found please share it

Answer (score 0):

We created a framework to allow actions like these on one of the last Firegento Hackathon.

The source code is available at: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/gamification

Unfortunately it does not inlcude a complete interactive game, but has some nice examples, e.g. searching for a specific word and for that showing new blocks. That could easily be changed to have a condition like finished game to enable a discount code.